# Website Input/Output using a premade .exe (Need direction)

Tags: programming-languages, web, io

I am trying to build a part of a website which takes in a text passage as input, and outputs the same text passage, except with the definition of each word appearing when the user rolls over (or clicks) any given word. I have a pre-made .exe file which maps input words to their definitions (takes in words from standard input and outputs the definition to standard output).

My problem, then, is to run user input through the .exe file on the website's server, then put the output back onto the page. It seems like a fairly trivial problem, but I have no idea where to start.

So my questions are: is this project even possible? If so, what languages/tools do I need to be able to use in order to implement it? Are there keywords that describe what I'm talking about that I could use to look up tutorials/solutions on the Web?

I have rudimentary knowledge of PHP, HTML, and Javascript, but so little experience that I can't judge whether (and how) they can be used to approach this problem.

Note: I do not have access to the .exe source, so I must use the .exe itself as my input-output mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

With AJAX and PHP, you can do accomplish this with minimal effort.

JavaScript's AJAX features would send the word you input to the PHP page, and from the PHP page, you can run the external exe file with the sent word as an argument (sanitize it, please. People can inject code which will explode your servers!):

```
<?php

$word = $_POST['input_word']; // MAKE SURE YOU SANITIZE THIS. If you don't, system security goes down the toilet.

exec('myprogram.exe ' + $word, $output_array);

print_r($output_array);

?>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much for the pointer. A follow-up question, though: how come I need to sanitize the input? If someone enters a word that isn't recognized by the dictionary, it just outputs "word not found"...